# My C++ program gets" ... .exe has stopped working" windows 7 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have written a C++ program in Visual Studio 2010. It *builds and runs fine in the IDE* (even when running without debugger, in Release mode). However, whenever I run the executable from the command prompt, I get an "... .exe has stopped working" error message.

How can I figure out what's causing it to crash? Do I have to include something else in the command line if I use additional libraries/headers? Are there errors that make it through the Visual Studio IDE, but cause problems when running the program on the outside?

I'm not including my code, because there's way to much of it...

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your code and how you configured your project here.

Comment: Could the path difference cause a problem? I mean when you run it in the IDE the current folder is the folder containing the sln file. If you run it from the command line the current folder would be whatever folder you are in your cmd.exe session.

Comment: If it is not a path issue perhaps you have Undefined Behavior.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a path or library error. Otherwise, it would say a library couldn't be found.

Comment: Are you loading any files? If so make sure you check the return code for failures.

Comment: An additional source of problems comes with .dlls. Are you sure the correct dll is being loaded? Could there be a different version of a dll in the path than what the ide has in its paths? Could a debug dll be loaded in a release config or viseversa? Could a dll compiled with a different version of Visual Studio be in your path. It is not generally safe to use a dll compiled with a different version of visual studio or mix debug and release.

Comment: @drescherjm I print using std::cout if a file was not opened successfully. Would I be seeing these messages if in fact the file failed to open? Because all I'm getting right now is that error message.

Comment: We would need to see a code sample for that.

Comment: @drescherjm How do I check to see if the correct dll is being loaded?

Comment: I think you have a stack overflow due to uninitialised variables.

Comment: @molbdnilo but wouldn't that error come up when I run it in VS 2010?

Comment: @awilds If you run in the debugger, VS zeroes your variables for you.

Comment: @molbdnilo by "run in the debugger", do you mean in Debug Mode? Because I've run it in Release Mode, and it runs fine.

Comment: @awilds No, I mean that you press F5, which causes VS to use "special" memory management. To run without the debugger, press Ctrl+F5 (I think, I don't have a VS handy).

Comment: @molbdnilo I ran it in Visual Studio without the debugger, and it still runs fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: Verify that all variables are initialized and pointers are initialized and pointing to valid locations.

Comment: @drescherjm had the correct solution to my problem. I didn't have the complete directory in the file names for the files I was loading. Thanks everyone for your comments. I've learned more than just the answer to my question.

Comment: @awilds Could you please answer your own question and accept the answer so that those who are looking for a solution wouldn't have to read all the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was incomplete directories for the files I was loading. I neglected to check for a successful open or use try/catch. It was running fine in the IDE because the file directory was in a subdirectory of the working directory. When I tried to run it from the command prompt, the relative directory was no longer valid. I changed the filenames to their complete directories, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

If your program had been rendered in Debug mode, try rendering it in Release mode and then retry.

Comment: I built it in Release mode to begin with.